# Calculating yearly log return from daily closing price in R for a panel of companies

Tags: r, return, panel-data

I have a panel data set of 34 banks from 2007 to 2020. I need to calculate the yearly log return from the daily adjusted closing stock prices of these banks. The data structure is as follows:

[image]

The date after importing to R is in POSIXct format while prices are in number format. There are in total 121323 observations.

Can anyone help me with the codes to calculate annual returns from daily prices? One of the problems is accounting for the panel data structure, the return calculation for Bank A has to end on the last date and the process has to repeat for Bank B and end on the last date so on. In the above data structure, the return calculation has to end on 07-01-2007 for Bank A. I have tried using quantmod but was unsuccessful. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works if the data is in the posted format.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(bank, year) %>%
  summarize(LogReturns = log(last(price)) - log(first(price)))
```

---

### Test data

```
library(quantmod)

from <- as.Date("2010-01-01")
to <- Sys.Date()

getSymbols("GOOGL", from = from, to = to)
getSymbols("MSFT", from = from, to = to)

df1 <- data.frame(date = index(GOOGL), price = GOOGL[,4])
df2 <- data.frame(date = index(MSFT), price = MSFT[,4])
names(df1)[2] <- "price"
names(df2)[2] <- "price"
df1$bank <- "GOOGL"
df2$bank <- "MSFT"
df1 <- rbind(df1, df2)
rm(GOOGL, MSFT, df2)
```

Comment: After running the code,this is the error enountered - Error in View : Problem with `mutate()` column `Year`.
ℹ `Year = format(Date, "%Y")`.
x object 'Date' not found

Comment: The data structure is as follows tibble [88,315 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)  $ bank : chr [1:88315] "Citi Bank" "Citi Bank" "Citi Bank" "Citi Bank" ...  $ date : POSIXct[1:88315], format: "2007-01-02" "2007-01-03" ...  $ price: num [1:88315] 89.2 90 89.2 88.5 89.7 ...

Comment: @learning_r You should post that data structure in the question where it's more readable but thanks. The problem is that you have lower case `date` and my example has upper case `Date`. And the same for `Bank`. The column in my mock up data named `Close` is your `price`. It is corrected now, see if it works.